# Spring Security session/xsrf configuration by path

Tags: java, spring, security, session, spring-security

I have an existing Web application that uses spring security for authentication. It is also using session management to allow the user to be logged in for a predefined period of time, and XSRF tokens to prevent XSS attacks.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
    .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .headers().addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Server",""))
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(restEntryPoint())
    .and()  
    .logout().addLogoutHandler(myLogoutHandler())
    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler())
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login", "/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).denyAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD).denyAll()  
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider)
        .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
    .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

This works great for the Web application. However, now I am requested to add a configuration that would let third party client applications to invoke my services via pure REST calls, i.e. they should be completely stateless and use http basic authentication - no session should be created and xsrf should be disabled (I think...).

I can define a shared URL path for all those client API calls. But how can I leverage my existing security configuration and server to support both requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

Spring security allows you use multiple configurations based on order. In the documentation, it gives the following example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultiHttpSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) { 1
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)                                                        2
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration                                                   4
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin();
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, /api would be permitted only for ADMIN roles, while other paths will be configured with the default FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

See more at [this URL](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity):